# Switch vs dictionary with double keys

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I am making a Unity game (C# 2.0) and it is the first time I do anything that requires the best performance possible. When a mission ends, the player is given certain amounts of resources depending on a time factor which is held by the mission object. There are 4 resources in total, so I was using 4 16-long switches-on-int (time*1000), one switch per resource.

```
static int resource1reward(double time) 
{
   int time2 = time*1000;
   switch (time2)
   {

   }
}
```

Looking at some posts I decided to try using 4 Dictionaries.

```
 Dictionary<double, int> resource1dic = new Dictionary<double, int>(16);
 static int resource1dicreward(double time)
 {
     return resource1[time];
 }
```

Using  a  stopwatch, I saw a **huge** difference between calling the (1) 4 methods; and (2) one method that looked up the 4 dictionaries.

1. 10 to 15 ms
2. 0 to 2 ms

The problem is that I still have a very long static method that initializes the 4 dictionaries. They all have the same keys (time switch) but different values. Is there any better/cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Create a structure that maps to your use case and use *that* as the value in your dictionary.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot - I already use that

Comment: You already use what? In your example the value in your dictionary is an `int` and you state you have 4 dictionaries. What you seem to *want* is a `Dictionary<string, SomeCustomType>` where `SomeCustomType` has four `int` fields.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I do not need custom types for this, my resources are just ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your business logic is a bit unclear, but in regards to the Dictionary object initialization/performance issue, the solution below may serve as a valid alternative. Pertinent to your use-case, you can declare `Dictionary<double, int>` as shown in the following sample C# code snippet:

```
public static  Dictionary<double, int> SampleDictionary =new Dictionary<double, int> 
{ 
    { 3.1, 3},
    { 3.14, 3},
    { 3.1415, 3},
    { 2.72, 2},
    { 2.728, 2}
};
```

It will be very fast and rather straightforward. Hope this may help.

Comment: That's what I am using right now. The thing is that I end up with 4 declarations like
private static Dictionary<double, int> Sample1 = new Dictionary<double, int> { {1.1, 1}, {1.2, 2} //continue to 16 } Is this really the simplest?

Comment: I would say Yes, and it should be also very fast (addressing your primary performance concern). If you are satisfied with the answer, then please mark it accepted. Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

How about a setup like this:

```
Dictionary<Resource, Dictionary<double, int>> rewards = new Dictionary<Resource, Dictionary<double, int>>();

public class Mission
{
    public Resource ResourceToAward { get; set; }
    public double Time { get; set; }
}

public enum Resource
{
    ResourceOne,
    ResourceTwo,
    ResourceThree,
    ResourceFour
}
```

From some simple testing, I'm seeing the actual `int` value being consistently accessed in about **0.9** milliseconds.

```
Mission theMission = new Mission()
{
    ResourceToAward = Resource.ResourceFour,
    Time = 15
};

Resource resource = theMission.ResourceToAward;
double time = theMission.Time;

int resourceAmountAwarded = rewards[resource][time];
```

Just a suggestion, I would create the `Dictionary<Resource, Dictionary<double, int>>` object BEFORE starting the mission so there's no unneeded time added to the mission time.

Comment: I am not being able to understand how following that approach would allow me to delete code repetition, what I am using now is `internal static int[] giveRewards() { int[] returner = { resource1dic[time], resource2dic[time], resource3dic[time], resource4dic[time] }` and create the dictionaries in the class' static constructor

Comment: @user3932049 What code is being repeated in your program? You have to initialize the dictionaries somewhere, and if they are all different with no pattern, you really can't streamline it much more without finding 4 separate equations that approximate the values.

Comment: ok, that is what I was worried about. Thought there could be a different approach that maybe didn't involve dictionaries/switches. I might end up serializing the dictionary objects and fetching them from my database. Thanks

Comment: @user3932049 Well...are you worried more about "best performance possible" or "simplicity of initializing the dictionaries"?

Comment: both :) will see if I can find anything else to accomplish this